# Facebook Open Graph - Filtering custom actions by custom parameter

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am building a facebook app where a user can 'love' 'pics' (those are the action and object names) from our library of user submitted photos for each of our products. Whenever a user loves a pic, I also send a (required) custom parameter which is the product id.

Is there a way to retrieve the current user's love actions for a particular product id? I am using the javascript fb sdk. I am trying to keep as much facebook related stuff off out of my back end system, so I would prefer to not store user data in my database.

Thanks for any help/advice,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do the filtering yourself, but yes, you can do this. Try something like

```
// This will return everything the user has loved
FB.api('/me/<your app namespace>:love', function(response) {
  for(var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
    var post = response.data[i];
    // Make sure that this is a post about loving a pic
    // and that the product_id is what we're looking for
    if(post.data.hasOwnProperty('pic') &&
       post.data.hasOwnProperty('product_id') &&
       post.data.product_id == desiredProductId) {
      // This is a post for loving a pic for the desired product id
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: That's what I have been doing so far, but I was hoping there would be a way to filter it in the API (so i don't have to page the API results as much)